# axios in vue js send request as string , not object

Tags: javascript, php, vue.js, axios

how can i resolve this problem  ? 
this is main.js
I want to send the name to the server via  axios in vuejs
But I can't get name from $_Request

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import axios from 'axios'

Vue.config.productionTip = false
Vue.prototype.$http = axios

new Vue({
  render: h => h(App),
}).$mount('#app')
```

and this is my template script

```
export default {

  data() {
    return {
    header:{headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    }},
      name:null,
      r:null,
    }

  },
  methods: {
    post:function(){
      this.$http.post('http://127.0.0.1/saver.php',{
          name:this.name,
        },this.header).then(r => {
       this.r=r;
       // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
       console.log(typeof {name:this.name})
      }).catch(err => {
   // eslint-disable-next-line no-console
   console.log(err.response.data)
});
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

and this is my php server side code :

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
header('Content-Type: application/json');
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST' && !empty($_REQUEST))
{

    print_r($_REQUEST);
}
?>
```

params :

[image: params]

and this is response that returned from server :

[image: response server]

Comment: @nullisnotundefined  Array
(
    [{"name":null}] => 
)

Comment: It sends it as a string, JSON string. Is there a reason why you don't use JSON on server side? If there is, you have to stringify the object yourself, afaik axios doesn't handle application/x-www-form-urlencoded in a specific way.

Comment: @EstusFlask i just want to send name parameter to server and get it with $_Request['name'] or $_Post['name']   what changes should i make ?

Answer (score 1):

As [Axios documentation](https://github.com/axios/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format) states,

> By default, axios serializes JavaScript objects to JSON. To send data
>   in the application/x-www-form-urlencoded format instead, you can use
>   one of the following options.
>
> <...>
>
> In a browser, you can use the URLSearchParams API
>
> <...>
>
> Alternatively, you can encode data using the qs library

It should be:

```
this.$http.post('http://127.0.0.1/saver.php', qs.stringify({
  name:this.name,
}),this.header)
```

Alternatively, server side can be modified to use JSON payload exclusively.